# Trying to read a file from master is not working on github action

Tags: node.js, github, github-actions

I have a js file like this

```
// test.js
exec(`git show master:src/path/to/my.json`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('failed', stderr);
        return;
    }
    ....
}
```

and a script cmd

```
// package.json
scripts: {
    doIt: "node test.js"
}
```

Executing this in github action

```
...
   - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.4
      with:
        fetch-depth: 0
    - name: DoIt
      run: yarn doIt
...
```

but getting error:

```
failed fatal: invalid object name master
```

Here is the github action output

```
* [new branch]          master                  -> origin/master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the default naming branch has [changed on GitHub](https://github.com/github/renaming), from `master` to `main`, check the one for the repository accessed by your GitHub action.

If the default branch is `main`, `master` would not exist.

Adding fetch-depth:0 is a good idea in order to fetch the all history (therefore all the branches), as seen in [issue 438](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/438#issuecomment-773284400)

But a workaround is: `git show origin/master:src/path/to/my.json`, as suggested in teh comments will work even if the master branch was not properly updated.

Comment: default name is master, the doIt.js file is running fine on my local

Comment: @coure2011 Then the repository has not been properly checked out, and the GitHub Action would not, in that case, see the master branch.

Comment: I just added fetch-depth: 0 to checkout all branches, in output I can also see all branches, but still the same issue

Comment: Ok found it out it should be origin/master instead of just master

Comment: @coure2011 Good catch. I have updated the answer accordingly.